# Import Excel Macro and run it with VBS

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I would like to create a vbs script that will open an .xlsx document, import a macro and run the macro. For my use, the .xlsx document's name will vary - so I may need a wildcard for the filename. This is what I have so far:

```
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.application")
xl.Application.Workbooks.Open "\\path\Missed_Scans\Report\Report.xlsx"
xl.Application.Visible = True
x1.VBProject.VBComponents.Import "\\path\Missed_Scans\Missed_Scans.bas"
x1.Save
xl.Application.run "'Report.xlsx'!Missed_Scans"
Set xl = Nothing
```

The above script will open 'report.xlsx' but it does not seem to correctly import or run the macro. It is not necessary for report.xlsx to be opened (visibly or otherwise) so long as the macro is imported and run.

EDIT

Here is the macro:

```
Attribute VB_Name = "Module1"
Sub Missed_Scans()
Attribute Missed_Scans.VB_ProcData.VB_Invoke_Func = " \n14"
'
' Missed_Scans Macro
'

'
    Sheets("Incomplete_ASINs").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$52951").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="SDF8"
    Columns("B:D").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="\\path\Missed_Scans\Report\Missed_Scans.xlsx" _
        , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is the `Save` (as a non-macro-enabled workbook) causing the macro to be removed?  Why do you need to put the macro into the workbook - why not just do the equivalent actions within your VBS code?

Comment: @YowE3K I am a VBS noobie. I do not need the macro in the workbook. What I am trying to accomplish is to sort a particular column and then copy several columns out to a new doc (this is done with the macro). I am happy to do all of that from VBS, but lacked the know-how to convert the macro to VBS. I will add the macro code to my initial post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code may well be giving issues due to the use of `x1` which hasn't been set.

You probably intended to use

```
Set x1 = xl.Application.Workbooks.Open("\\path\Missed_Scans\Report\Report.xlsx")
```

But I would have expected that to actually crash rather than just not correctly importing the macro.

---

I suspect that you can avoid using the VBA macro if you just use the equivalent code in VBS:

```
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.application")
xl.Application.Visible = True

Dim wb1
Set wb1 = xl.Application.Workbooks.Open("\\path\Missed_Scans\Report\Report.xlsx")
Dim wb2
Set wb2 = xl.Workbooks.Add

wb1.Sheets("Incomplete_ASINs").Range("$A$1:$J$52951").AutoFilter 1, "SDF8"
wb1.Sheets("Incomplete_ASINs").Columns("B:D").Copy
wb2.Worksheets(1).Paste
wb2.Worksheets(1).Rows(1).AutoFilter
wb2.SaveAs "\\path\Missed_Scans\Report\Missed_Scans.xlsx", 51, , , , False
wb2.Close
wb1.close
xl.Quit
Set xl = Nothing
```

Note: I'm not an expert in VBS, so I **hope** that code works.  Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: Perfection! Thanks.

Bonus Points: How do I silence the prompt at the end to save 'report.xlsx'? I don't care if it saves or not.

Comment: @Garrett `wb1.Close False` should stop it from asking whether you want to save it.